# Merry Christmas interactive message

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking to style a page with a "*Merry Christmas*" message and the following requirement:

- The letters light-on and light-off one by one (starts with "*M*" and finishes with "*s*" and start again)

I tried with jQuery but can't nail it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Merry Christmas!</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
 .merry-christmas{
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:200px;
 }
</style>
<body>

<div class="merry-christmas">
    Merry Christmas!
</div>
 
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var message = $("div").text();
        for (var x = 0; x < message.length; x++)
        {
            var c = message.charAt(x);
            alert(c);//How to change the class of the letter?
        }
    });
</script>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My variant https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/dmr2ksy4/ :

1) use `setInterval` (or `setTimeout`)

2) don't forget about css

Answer (score 2):

Based on Jordan S's solution:

```js
var text = $(".merry-christmas").text().split('');
$(".merry-christmas").empty();

text.forEach(function(letter) {
  var letter = $("<span>").text(letter).addClass('letter');
  $(".merry-christmas").append(letter);
});

var current = 0;
window.setInterval(function() {
  $s = $(".letter");
  if (current == $s.length) { current = 0;  }
  $s.removeClass('blink');
  $($s[current++]).addClass('blink');
}, 250);
```

```css
.letter {  font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 50px; color: #0eaf36;  }
.blink {  color: red;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="merry-christmas">Merry Christmas!</div>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/10tkqn57/1/)